# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de un select con múltiple?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Bueno estoy haciendo un proyecto donde ocupo hacer registros de reportes o servicios mediante un formulario donde en un campo de nombre "secretarias" de tipo select multiple al seleccionar más de 1, me llene en otro campo dentro del mismo formulario a los usuarios que están asignados desde la base de forma estática a los encargados de secretaría por **js** que se encarga de mandar objetos y esta a su vez llegue al **web service** y después al **dao**. Hasta ahorita tenía ya funcional un **select** normal, sin embargo, lo ocupo con múltiple. A continuación les muestro como tengo mi estructura, donde se observa el **select** de "secretarias" mediante el **id** "secretariaTxt" los pinta llamando a la función en el **onload** del **body SelecccionarSecretaria**.

[image: TABLA DE USUARIOS CON SU RESPECTIVA SECRETARIA DE MYSQL]

```
<body onload="SelecccionarSecretaria(), SelecccionarSecretaria2(), tablaRegistros();"> 

                    <label for="nombreTxt">Nombre</label>
                    <input value="alberto" type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreTxt" required  />  
                    <label for="direccionTxt">Dirección</label>
                    <input value="mexico" type="text" class="form-control" id="direccionTxt" required  /> 
                    <label for="coloniaTxt">Colonia</label>
                    <input  value="mexico" type="text" class="form-control" id="coloniaTxt" required/> 
                    <label for="telefonoTxt">Telefono</label>
                    <input value="1234567" style="font-size: medium;" type="number" class="form-control" id="telefonoTxt"required  /> 
                    <label for="reporte_servicioTxt">Reporte o Servicio</label>
                    <textarea id="reporte_servicioTxt" rows="4" cols="20" class="form-control"></textarea> 
                      <label for="referencias_ubicacionTxt">Referencias de Ubicación</label>
                    <textarea  value="cerca de chedraiu" class="form-control" id="referencias_ubicacionTxt" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea> 
                    </th> 
                    <label for="seguimientoTxt">Seguimiento</label>
                    <textarea name="comentarios"  class="form-control" id="seguimientoTxt" rows="4" cols="20">   
                    </textarea>  
                    <label for="conCopiaTxt">C.C.P</label>
                    <textarea value="Secretaria Publica"  class="form-control" id="conCopiaTxt" rows="4" cols="20">   
                    </textarea> 
                    <label for="secretariaTxt">Secretaria</label>  
       <select id="secretariaTxt" multiple="multiple" style="font-size: medium;"  type="number" class="form-control"> 
                    </select> 
                    <label for="encargadoTxt">Encargado</label> 
                    <select type="text" multiple="" disabled="true"   style="font-size: medium;"  class="form-control" id="area_atiendeTxt" > 
                    </select>  
                    <button onclick="getValues()">Obtener Elementos</button>  
                            <label for="usuarioCapturaTxt">Usuario de Captura</label>
                    <input style="font-size: medium;" type="text"  class="form-control" id="usuarioCapturaTxt" disabled="true" value="<%=session.getAttribute("NombreUsuario")%>"  />  
                    <label for="estadoTxt">Estado</label>
                    <select style="font-size: medium;" onchange="colorFondoEstado(this)" style="background-color: limegreen;"  type="text" class="form-control"  id="estadoTxt" required autofocus> 
                        <option class="abierto" value="Abierto">Abierto</option>
                        <option  class="pendiente" value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
                        <option  class="resuelto" value="Resuelto">Resuelto</option>
                    </select>   
                    <label for="prioridadTxt">Prioridad</label>
                    <select  name="prioridadTxt"   style="font-size: medium;" name="fondo" type="text"   style="background-color: red;"  onchange="colorFondoPrioridad(this)" class="form-control"  id="prioridadTxt" required autofocus>
                        <option class="urgente" value="Urgente">Urgente</option>
                        <option class="alta" value="Alta">Alta</option>
                        <option  class="media" value="Media">Media</option>
                        <option class="baja" value="Baja">Baja</option>
                    </select> 
                    <label  for="abierto_diaTxt">Abierto el Dia</label>
                    <input value="2" style="font-size: medium;" type="date" class=" form-control" id="abierto_diaTxt" required autofocus/> 
                    <label for="fecha_solucionTxt">Fecha Aproximada de Solucion</label>
                    <input  value="2017-11-31"  style="font-size: medium;" type="date" class="form-control " id="fecha_solucionTxt" required autofocus/>

                    <label for="cantidad_diasTxt">Cantidad de Dias Abierto</label>
                    <input  value="1"style="font-size: medium;" type="number"  class="form-control" id="cantidad_diasTxt" required autofocus/>  
                    <label for="fecha_respuestaTxt">Fecha de Respuesta al Ciudadano</label>
                    <input  value="2017-11-31"  style="font-size: medium;" type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha_respuestaTxt" required autofocus/>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="RegistrarReportes()">Registrar Reporte </button>
                </div> 
    //CODIGO DE JS para pintar los valores 
 function getValues() {  
       var arreglo=[];  
                             var selectObject = document.getElementById("secretariaTxt"); 
                             for (var i = 0; i < selectObject.options.length; i++) { 
                                 if (selectObject.options[i].selected === true) {  
                                 arreglo.push(selectObject.options[i].value);
                    selectObject.options[i].value + '">' + selectObject.options[i].value + '</option>'); 
                      llenarCampoAreaAtiende(arreglo) ; 
             }
                             }
 
                         }
  
//Codigo donde se llena el campo de usuarios con sus respectivos encargados 
        function llenarCampoAreaAtiende(id) {
        alert("llenarCampoAreaAtiende"); 
        var sel = {ids}; 
        var peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();
        peticion.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
                var respuesta = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                var areaAtiende = respuesta.respuesta.areaAtiende;
                $('#area_atiendeTxt').html('');
                if (areaAtiende.length > 0) 
                {
                    $('#area_atiendeTxt');
                    for (var i = 0; i < areaAtiende.length; i++) { 
                        $('#area_atiendeTxt').append('<option  value="' + areaAtiende[i].idUsuario + '">' + areaAtiende[i].nombreUsuario + '</option>');
                    }
                } else {
                    $('#area_atiendeTxt').append('<option >NO HAY registros </option>');
                }
    
            }
        };
        peticion.open("GET", "http://localhost:etc/llenarAreaAtiende?parametro=" + JSON.stringify(sel), true);
        peticion.send();
    } 

//Codigo Service

    @GET
    @Path("llenarAreaAtiende")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response llenarAreaAtiende(@QueryParam("parametro") String departamento) throws ParseException {
        daoSecretaria = new DaoSecretaria();
        daoUsuario = new DaoUsuario();
        beanSecretaria = new BeanSecretaria();
        beanUsuario = new BeanUsuario();
        JSONObject objeto = null;

        try {
            objeto = new JSONObject(departamento);
          //  Queue cola=new AbstractQueue();
            //cola=objeto.getJSONObject("ids");
            System.out.println("Objetos array ---> " + objeto);
            beanUsuario.setIdUsuario(objeto.getInt("ids"));

        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error" + ex);
        }

        respuestas.put("areaAtiende", daoSecretaria.consultarSecretariasEspecifica(beanUsuario.getIdUsuario()));

        try {
            objeto = new JSONObject();
            objeto.put("respuesta", respuestas);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error en el segundo try: " + e);
        }
        Response.ResponseBuilder constructor = Response.ok(objeto.toString());
        constructor.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        constructor.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        return constructor.build();
    }
//codigo dao de consultarSecretariasEspecifica

public List<BeanUsuario> consultarSecretariasEspecifica(int idSecretaria) {
        BeanUsuario consultarUsuario=null;
        List<BeanUsuario> listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            con = Conexion.getConexion();
            pstm = con.prepareStatement("select usuarios.idUsuario, usuarios.nombreUsuario from secretarias inner join usuarios on secretarias.idUsuario=usuarios.idUsuario where nombreSecretaria=(select nombreSecretaria from secretarias where idSecretaria=?)");
            pstm.setInt(1, idSecretaria);
            rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        
            while (rs.next()) {
                
                consultarUsuario = new BeanUsuario();
                        consultarUsuario.setIdUsuario(rs.getInt("idUsuario"));
                        consultarUsuario.setNombreUsuario(rs.getString("nombreUsuario"));
                     
                        
                        listaUsuarios.add(consultarUsuario);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error en consultarSecretarias()" + ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
                pstm.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error en consultarSecretarias()" + e);
            }
        }
        return listaUsuarios;
    }
```

Comment: El `select` multiple te retorna un arreglo de campos seleccionados, la pregunta es, ¿El servicio está preparado para recibir un arreglo?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es recorrer el arreglo que obtienes del select, de la siguiente forma:

```js
// Write JavaScript here 
function getValues() {
    document.getElementById('listaElementos').innerHTML = '';
    var selectObject =document.getElementById("secretariaTxt");
    for (var i = 0; i < selectObject.options.length; i++) {
        if(selectObject.options[i].selected ==true){              
           document.getElementById('listaElementos').innerHTML += selectObject.options[i].value + '<br>';
          }
      }

}
```

```html
<select id="secretariaTxt" multiple="multiple" style="font-size: medium;"  type="number" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="4">Item 4</option>
    <option value="5">Item 5</option>
</select>

<button onclick="getValues()">Obtener Elementos</button>
<div id="listaElementos">

</div>
```

Comment: gracias por responder, si de hecho eso estoy tratando de hacer pero lo que no se bien es como pintarlo dentro de un input type=text esto para posteriromente registrarlo, lo que pasa es que tengo un formulario donde atraves de un select "secretariaTxt" se llena el campo de atiendeTxt dependiendo de la opcion que seleccione ya que las opciones de secretaria son enteros (idsecretarias) y dependiendo de ellos se les pinta el el idUsuario por que esta asignados asi, sin embargo no se como que si yo elijo 2 secretarias o mas me pinte sus respectivos usuarios

Comment: Al ir sumando con los select podrías agregar un '-' y con tenerlos divididos podrías hacer una función each, con un split y recorrer las distintas secretarias y seleccionar sus pacientes, al menos así se me ocurre pero yo no se si los pacientes están o no en una bd, no se como los llamas si por un ajax con objeto json, lo desconosco, pero intenta ver lo que te escribí y me comentas @alberto

Comment: gracias por ayudarme en esto la subi las imagenes como esta estructurado anteriormente si funciona pero seleccionando uno en especifico pero al momento de seleccionar varios no logro que me pinte los nombre correspondientes

Comment: Estimado, coloca la imagen de tu código como texto para poder editarlo, y no borres todo lo que escribiste antes, toda esa evidencia de código funciona, cuando lo tengas listo etiquetame con un `@` @alberto

Comment: @harifo, creo que ya, apenas me registre en la plataforma de antemano muchas gracias por ayudar, me he atorado en el Queue si me imprime los datos mediante un sout en el service:

 Objetos array ---> {"ids":["1","3"]}
Información:   Errororg.json.JSONException: JSONObject["ids"] is not an int.